# Convert all UPPERCASE to Capitalize in Google Sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, find-replace

I have a Google Sheet with multiple rows of large text blocks. Within the text, there are heading tags that contain phrases that are in ALL CAPS. For example,

```
<p>Some paragraph text.</p><h2>THIS IS MY HEADING</h2><p>More paragraph text.</p>
```

I need to isolate the text strings within h2 tags and convert to Capitalize instead of UPPERCASE. I'm struggling to find a good formula and/or regex find/replace to accomplish this. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=PROPER(LOWER(regexextract(A1,"h2>(.*)<\/h2")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract text.

```
=PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "<h2>(.*)<\/h2>"))
```

[image]

2. Replace and capitalize.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "<h2>.*<\/h2>", TEXTJOIN(B1,FALSE, "<h2>","</h2>"))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - that's perfect. However, I need to maintain the h2 tags. So, the result would be: <p>Some paragraph text.</p><h2>This Is My Heading</h2><p>More paragraph text.</p>

Comment: Fixed it to include the <h2> tag.

Comment: Nice - that works great.

Comment: One more for you - what if I have multiple <h2> tags in the same cell?

Comment: Actually - using Sublime Text I was able to do a regex find/replace and got it working. Thanks for the help.